# EF6: Trouble creating an table's index using Migration and ODP.NET

Tags: c#, entity-framework, plsql, entity-framework-migrations, odp.net

I use ODP.net with EntityFramework 6 Code first Migration. I installed in my project all necessary packages for using Oracle with EntityFramework. 
I try to create tables and their indexes.
My actions:

1. Create a table

   ```
   [Table("VSM_TP_REL")]
   public class DepRel
       {
       [Column("ID"), Key]
       public int Id { get; set; }

       [Column("FULLNAME", TypeName="varchar2"), Required, MaxLength(250)]
       public string FullName { get; set; }

       [Column("SEX", TypeName="varchar2"), Required, MaxLength(1), Index("IX_VSM_TP_REL")]
       public string Sex { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. I added Index annotation because I want to create index for Sex field.
3. Run add-migration command. It's ok.
4. Run update-database -verbose command and get a following script:

   ```
   begin
     execute immediate
     'create index "PROD"."IX_VSM_TP_REL" on "PROD"."VSM_TP_REL" ("SEX")';
   exception
   when others then
     if sqlcode <> -1408 then
       raise;
     end if;
   end;
   ```
5. After executing the script I get an error message:

   ```
   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved for member 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException,Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'.
      at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
   Type is not resolved for member 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException,Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'.
   ```

**Question 1:** Any pl/sql script is executed with same error. Why?

**Question 2:** How can i fix this problem?

Additional information.

To get a real error, I created a new console application.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<OracleDbContext, ConsoleApplication2.Migrations.Configuration>());
            var db = new OracleDbContext();                
            db.Database.Initialize(false);
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

After running my console applicattion I got the following error message:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the
>   following:
>
> begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return
>   select update while with << close current delete fetch lock insert
>   open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe.

The Author of [THIS ARTICLE](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/executing-sql-scripts-with-oracle-odp/) explains I get this error message because ODP.NET doesn't support CR/LF pair. He advises to run

```
command.CommandText = sql.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
```

But can I put this code in the system migration?

**QUESTION:** Tell me please, how can I intercept the script updating database and edit it?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and found an article on Oracle that indicate it would be a error on Oracle 10g database.

Try with an 11g version. I don't have theses errors anymore under this version.

Comment: Can you share the article with us?